# Exception has occurred: CLR/System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PSSnapInException when running simple PowerShell command

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm trying to run an example C# program that's supposed to invoke a simple PowerShell command.
Unfortunately, I'm getting the following error message:

```
Exception has occurred: CLR/System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PSSnapInException
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PSSnapInException' occurred in System.Management.Automation.dll: 'System error.'
   at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PSSnapInHelpers.LoadPSSnapInAssembly(PSSnapInInfo psSnapInInfo)
   at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.InitialSessionState.ImportPSSnapIn(PSSnapInInfo psSnapInInfo, PSSnapInException& warning)
   at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.InitialSessionState.CreateDefault()
   at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(PSHost host)
   at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace()
   at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Worker.CreateRunspaceIfNeededAndDoWork(Runspace rsToUse, Boolean isSync)
   at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvokeHelper[TInput,TOutput](PSDataCollection`1 input, PSDataCollection`1 output, PSInvocationSettings settings)
   at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvoke[TInput,TOutput](PSDataCollection`1 input, PSDataCollection`1 output, PSInvocationSettings settings)
   at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Invoke(IEnumerable input, PSInvocationSettings settings)
   at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Invoke()
   at ttps3.Program.Main(String[] args) in Z:\projects\easybell\ttps3\Program.cs:line 21
```

I'm running on C# SDK 5 and System.Management.Automation 7.1.3

Comment: What does the code look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.Management.Automation` is only usable in [very limited scenarios](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/depending-on-the-right-powershell-nuget-package-in-your-net-project/). you can install the `Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK` nuget package instead.

**Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK**

Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK is a meta-package that pulls together all of the components of the PowerShell SDK into a single NuGet package. A self-contained .NET application can use Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK to run arbitrary PowerShell functionality without depending on any external PowerShell installations or libraries.

**System.Management.Automation**

The `System.Management.Automation` package is the heart of the PowerShell SDK and exists on NuGet chiefly as an asset for Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK to pull in. However, it can also be used directly as a package for smaller hosting scenarios and version-targeting modules.

Specifically, the `System.Management.Automation` package may be a preferable provider of PowerShell functionality when:

- You’re only looking to use PowerShell language functionality (in the `System.Management.Automation.Language` namespace) like the PowerShell parser, AST and AST visitor APIs (for example for static analysis of PowerShell).
- You only wish to execute specific commands from the `Microsoft.PowerShell.Core` module and can execute them in a session state created with the `CreateDefault2` factory method.

**PowerShellStandard.Library and other PowerShell reference assemblies**

These reference assemblies do not include a runtime and require a global powershell installation that matches the reference assembly version.